# Fresco.initialize not working in Fragment

Tags: android, fresco

Fresco is not working when I am initializing it in the OnCreate or OnCreateView of the fragment. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize Fresco only once, in your custom Application.
Example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fresco.initialize(this);
  }
}
```

More info: http://frescolib.org/docs/